# how to coonect Redis on windows to remote server

Tags: c#, .net, redis

i have installed redis client on windows and try to connect Linux where redis server is installed. tried this command `redis-cli -h [ipAddress`

Comment: Please check your question its not completed.

Comment: connect with ssh first? ``ssh root@serverip`` then you have access to your server, then `redis-cli`

Comment: Hi, please try https://fastoredis.com